# Permission denied error when running docker image with rust binary

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

I am getting permission denied when trying to run a small rust cli app via a docker container. I can build the image fine, but when I try to run it I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:380: 
starting container process caused: exec: "./async-scraper": permission denied: 
unknown.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM clux/muslrust:1.56.1-stable as builder
WORKDIR /volume
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release ./async-scraper
RUN chmod +x ./async-scraper
ENTRYPOINT [ "./async-scraper","$@"]
```

Run cmd

```
sudo docker run --rm -it paul-k/web_scraper:latest - 
https://example-url-arg/
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "async_web_scraper"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "rat"
path = "src/main.rs"

[lib]
name = "async_scraper"

[dependencies]
select = "0.6.0-alpha.1"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.6", features = ["json"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3.1"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
url = "2.2.2"
error-chain = "0.12.4"
async-trait = "0.1.51"
simple-error = "0.1.9"
anyhow = "1.0"
log = "0.4.14"
env_logger = "0.9.0"
thiserror = "1.0.30"

[dev-dependencies]
httpmock = "0.6"
tokio-test = "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute a directory `"/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release"`. I advise you use `cargo install`:

```
RUN cargo install --path . --root /volume

# ...

COPY --from=builder /volume/bin/rat /volume/rat
WORKDIR /volume
ENTRYPOINT [ "./rat","$@"]
```

Comment: `"/volume/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/` has my executables. I did try what you said but it errored out with `Step 6/8 : COPY --from=builder /volume/bin/async-scraper /volume/async-scraper
COPY failed: stat volume/bin/async-scraper: file does not exist
`

Comment: @godhar I assume `async-scraper` was your binary name, please provide your cargo.toml in your question so

Comment: I added the cargo.toml.

Comment: thanks for the updates, I am new with rust. Indeed my binary is called`rat`. However, after running this new script, if I check `/volume/bin/rat` after the build stage, it's empty. To confirm, running the image errors with `exec: "./rat": stat ./rat: no such file or directory: unknown.`

Comment: @godhar be sure you workdir is `/volume`

Comment: Legend! It worked. Thanks a lot. I do get an error, but that is from `/src`.

`ReqError(reqwest::Error { kind: Builder, url: Url { scheme: "javascript", cannot_be_a_base: true, username: "", password: None, host: None, port: None, path: "void(0)", query: None, fragment: None }', src/domain_requests.rs:30:53`

This one is for another day. Thanks again Stargateur